# StructureMap nested dependency handling

Tags: dependency-injection, structuremap

I'm using StructureMap for dependency injection and I want to inject NHibernate sessions with it. I have the following code:

```
private static Container _container { get; set; }

static MyClass() 
{
    _container = new Container(r =>
    {
        r.For<ISessionFactory>().Singleton()
            .Use(NHibernate.GetSessionFactory());

        r.For<ISession>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
            .Use(_container.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession());
    });
}
```

However, I can't help but think that referencing _container from within the _container's initialization seems awkward. Is this an acceptable practice? Is it going to backfire down the road? Is there  a better way? How do you handle dependencies that require the creation of another dependency to create themselves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems unnecessary to use a reference to an instance of the container inside the container. You have access to the container inside the Use-method through a lambda.

```
 r.For<ISession>().HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped()
  .Use(c => c.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession());
```

This will ensure that the instance is fetched every time you're in a new HttpContext. It looks to me like your way will create a singleton since the `_container.GetInstance<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()` will only be executed once upon configuration.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. I missed the overload that provided the container for a lambda expression.